# Probability theory problem involving presents

Tags: number-theory, probability-theory

Santa Claus prepared meticulously $n$ distinct labeled presents, each designated for precisely one recipient.

E. Scrooge takes all the labels, shuffles them and redistributes them at random among the presents.

Now, fix $k ≤ n$. What is the probability that precisely $k$ persons will receive their originally designated present?

How can I quickly answer such a question? It is a question from the textbook but I cannot get the right answer. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can choose the recipients who receive their designated presents in $n \choose k$ ways. The remaining $n-k$ presents do not go to their designated recipients so this is equivalent to a Derangement of $n-k$ objects. The total number of distributions is simply $n \choose k$ $D_{n-k}$ where 
$$D_{n-k} = (n-k)!\sum_{i=0}^{n-k}\frac{(-1)^i}{i!}$$
The total number of distributions in $n!$ since the first present can go to any recipient, the second present can go to any of the remaining recipients and so on.
$$P= \frac{{n \choose k}D_{n-k}}{n!}$$

Please verify if necessary. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Note that you have $n!$ possible permutations. The number of permutaions $\sigma$ that for exatly $k$ indexes, $\sigma(k) = k$ is $\binom{n}{k} \cdot \; !(n - k)$, where $!x$ is the [subfactorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement) of $x$. So the probability is $\frac{\binom{n}{k} \cdot \; !(n - k)}{n!}$